# Django + MongoEngine, type object 'TitleRecord' has no attribute '_default_manager'

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Im using Django with `mongoengine`, when i trying to open model (http://localhost:8000/adminv2/api/titlerecord/) in `mongo_admin` got an error

> models.py

```py
from mongoengine import Document, fields as models


class TitleRecord(Document):
    text = models.StringField(max_length=256)
    # TODO
    attatched_file = models.FileField()

    duration = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

> admin.py

```py
from .models import TitleRecord

from django_mongoengine import mongo_admin as admin


class TitleRecordAdmin(admin.DocumentAdmin):
    model = TitleRecord
    fields = ('text',) 

admin.site.register(TitleRecord, TitleRecordAdmin)
```

> urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django_mongoengine import mongo_admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('adminv2/', mongo_admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
    path('api/', include('api.urls'))
] 

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

> Traceback:

```sh
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/adminv2/api/titlerecord/

Django Version: 3.0.5
Python Version: 3.7.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'rest_framework_mongoengine',
 'django_mongoengine',
 'django_mongoengine.mongo_auth',
 'django_mongoengine.mongo_admin',
 'account',
 'djoser',
 'api']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\flutter-app\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\flutter-app\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\flutter-app\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\flutter-app\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 607, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\flutter-app\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\flutter-app\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\flutter-app\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 231, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\flutter-app\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\flutter-app\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\flutter-app\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1678, in changelist_view
    cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\flutter-app\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 741, in get_changelist_instance
    sortable_by,
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\flutter-app\env\lib\site-packages\django_mongoengine\mongo_admin\views.py", line 17, in __init__
    super(DocumentChangeList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\flutter-app\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py", line 57, in __init__
    self.root_queryset = model_admin.get_queryset(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\flutter-app\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 357, in get_queryset
    qs = self.model._default_manager.get_queryset()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /adminv2/api/titlerecord/
Exception Value: type object 'TitleRecord' has no attribute '_default_manager'
```